# Cannot install ZBar for Python 2.7.9 on Windows 10: Errors in zbar.h

Tags: python, pip, zbar

I'm trying to install ZBar on my computer, running `pip install zbar` from the Command Window (as admin). However, I keep getting the following errors:

```
zbarmodule.c

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(685) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(687) : error C2085: 'zbar_processor_parse_config' : not in formal parameter list

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(687) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(761) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(763) : error C2085: 'zbar_processor_error_spew' : not in formal parameter list

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(763) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(768) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'const'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(777) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(778) : error C2085: 'zbar_processor_get_error_code' : not in formal parameter list

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(778) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(882) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(884) : error C2085: 'zbar_video_error_spew' : not in formal parameter list

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(884) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(889) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'const'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(897) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(898) : error C2085: 'zbar_video_get_error_code' : not in formal parameter list

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(898) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(968) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(970) : error C2085: 'zbar_window_error_spew' : not in formal parameter list

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(970) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(975) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'const'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(984) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(985) : error C2085: 'zbar_window_get_error_code' : not in formal parameter list

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(985) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1050) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1052) : error C2085: 'zbar_image_scanner_parse_config' : not in formal parameter list

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1052) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1141) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1143) : error C2085: 'zbar_decoder_parse_config' : not in formal parameter list

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1143) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1276) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1278) : error C2085: 'zbar_scan_rgb24' : not in formal parameter list

C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1278) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

zbarmodule.c(65) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

zbarmodule.c(66) : error C2065: 'major' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(66) : error C2065: 'minor' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(68) : error C2065: 'major' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(68) : error C2065: 'minor' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(133) : error C2275: 'zbar_error_t' : illegal use of this type as an expression

        C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(121) : see declaration of 'zbar_error_t'

zbarmodule.c(133) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ei'

zbarmodule.c(133) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(134) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(134) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(134) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(135) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(135) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(136) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(146) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression

        c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'

zbarmodule.c(146) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(147) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(151) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(151) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(151) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(152) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(152) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(152) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(153) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(153) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(153) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(154) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(154) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(154) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(155) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(155) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(155) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(156) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(156) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(156) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(157) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(157) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(157) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(158) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(158) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(158) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(159) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(159) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(159) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(160) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(160) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(160) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(162) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(162) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(162) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(163) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(164) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(164) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(164) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(164) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(164) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(167) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression

        c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'

zbarmodule.c(167) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(167) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(167) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(167) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_GetDict' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(169) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(169) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(169) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(171) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(171) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(171) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(183) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an expression

        c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'

zbarmodule.c(183) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(185) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(185) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(185) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(186) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(186) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(186) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(187) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(187) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(187) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(188) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(188) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(188) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(189) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(189) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(189) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(190) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(190) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(190) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(191) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(191) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(191) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(192) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(192) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(192) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(193) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(193) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(193) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(194) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(194) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(194) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(195) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(195) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(195) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(196) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(196) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(196) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

zbarmodule.c(197) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier

zbarmodule.c(197) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'

zbarmodule.c(197) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

error: command 'C:\\Users\\Userzzz\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I haven't written the zbar.h file, so I'm not sure how I even go about fixing these errors. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it with an executable,  downloaded from https://github.com/jacobvalenta/zbar-py27-msi

Comment: Wow the [python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558328/295686) [tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) didn't work for me, but this installer got me past that `pip install`